# AWS Codebuild use project role permissions if specified access_key and secret_key in environment variables does not have permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

In CodeBuild project if the user sets access and secret keys through environment variables and specified access keys does not have required permissions, Can we make the project use project service role permissions assuming that the project service role has all permissions.

I know the explanation is a bit iffy, comment below for more info.

```py
if user_creds_has_required_permissions:
    use user_creds # given through environment variables.
else:
    use default codebuild service role # assume service role has all permissions required for codebuild.
```

Comment: I don't really understand what u trying to get here, but u can simply create image on your local and add to this image your creds. push it to  ecr and codebuild will pull this image.

Comment: @SaggiBashari suppose I have many users with different credentials and the given user credentials through env variables dosen't have permissions to some resources in aws, I want to use codebuild service role permissions. Added a edit so that it will help you understand.